# SQL Query Optimisation on a Date Column

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have a table which is never updated and rarely inserted into. I need to optimise this table for rapid querying on a date column and an nvachar(32).

I'm adding Index's to the table, and I'm unsure if it would be best for performance to split the date column up into separate columns e.g. a separate column for year, month and day or just leave the date column as is.

Queries will basically be on the nvarchar column and year column, or may include year, and month, and day.

What I will actually be doing is running a SOUNDEX clause over a surname column and a date column

e.g. something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Surname]
FROM [dbo].[sometable]
WHERE YEAR(Datecolumn) = 2011 AND SOUNDEX(Surname) = SOUNDEX('smith')
```

What would be best for performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the way you are gonna do your filters, then an index is useless since you are applying functions to those columns. For the `DateColumn` you could do

```
DateColumn >= '20110101' AND DateColumn < 20120101
```

You can also create a computed column with the year and month if its really necessary and create an index on those columns. For the `Surname` column I don't think there is much to do, the `SOUNDEX` search will be slow, and won't use an index the way you are using it. You can still think in creating a persisted computed column with the result of the `SOUNDEX` function applied to `Surname`, create an index on that column and do your filter using the computed column. This should speed up your query.

Comment: I was typing the exact same answer.  You could use "between" as I think it reads better. You should check the execution plan to make sure you have the proper index and that it will actually use it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm testing now. Are you sure that applying a function e.g. YEAR(DateColumn) = 2011 means that the index is useless. Is this dependent on database technology as I'm using SQL Server 2008 and in the execution plan it seems to using the index on the date column even though I'm applying Year function to it?

Answer (score 0):

For datetime column you can use where clause as:

```
WHERE DateColumn BETWEEN '01/01/2011'  AND '01/01/2012'
```

But if your're going to do any operation on a column in where clause index is useless. What can i offer is storing precalculated SOUNDEX value of Surname in a separate column

Comment: If the date column has a time component, using between could cause you to miss data.